# How to force a symfony version on github actions when testing a bundle

Tags: php, symfony, testing, github-actions

I'm trying to test a bundle on different versions of Symfony with github actions. I tried to configure my job as explained in [Best practices for reusable bundles](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/best_practices.html#continuous-integration)

Here is my job:

```yaml
name: Bundle test

on:
  push: ~
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.operating-system }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        operating-system: [ ubuntu-latest ] #, windows-latest ]
        php: [ '7.4', '8.0' ]
        symfony: ['4.4', '5.2', '5.3']
    name: On ${{ matrix.operating-system }} with PHP ${{ matrix.php }} and Symfony ${{ matrix.symfony }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master

      - name: Validate composer.json
        run: composer validate --strict

      - name: Setup PHP ${{ matrix.php }}
        uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: ${{ matrix.php }}
        run: php -v

      - name: Export Symfony version ${{ matrix.symfony }}
        run: export SYMFONY_REQUIRE=${{ matrix.symfony }}

      - name: Install symfony/flex
        run: composer global require --no-progress --no-scripts --no-plugins symfony/flex

      - name: Composer update on php ${{ matrix.php }} and symfony ${{ matrix.symfony }}
        run: composer update --prefer-dist --no-progress
```

Even if I export Symfony version with symfony/flex, composer always install Symfony 5.3 (which is the current stable version)

```
Composer update on php 7.4 and symfony 4.4
Run composer update --prefer-dist --no-progress
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 85 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
 ... ... ... ...
  - Locking symfony/console (v5.3.0)
```

If needed, here is the requirement lines of my `composer.json` file:

```json
{
    ...
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.4|^8.0",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "^4.4|^5.2|^5.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "9.*",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "^2.19",
        "nyholm/symfony-bundle-test": "^1.7"
    },
    ...
}
```

EDIT: On my local dev computer, it works fine, when I run:

```sh
export SYMFONY_REQUIRE=5.2
symfony composer global require --no-progress --no-scripts --no-plugins symfony/flex
symfony composer update --prefer-dist --no-progress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `export` command isn't environment-proof.

Finally, I removed these lines:

```yaml
  - name: Export Symfony version ${{ matrix.symfony }}
    run: export SYMFONY_REQUIRE=${{ matrix.symfony }}
```

and updated the last line:

```yaml
  - name: Composer update on php ${{ matrix.php }} and symfony ${{ matrix.symfony }}
    run: composer update --prefer-dist --no-progress
```

to

```yaml
  - name: Composer update on php ${{ matrix.php }} and symfony ${{ matrix.symfony }}
    run: SYMFONY_REQUIRE=${{ matrix.symfony }} composer update --prefer-dist --no-progress
```

This perhaps is a partial solution, because I guess that it will failed on windows-os.

Comment: Did you figure out a foolproof solution?